# Maria DB AES_DECRYPT() with CBC encryption mode

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes

mysql shows error : Error in query (1582): Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'AES_DECRYPT'
I'm using mariaDB
I have tried differnet options but all ends up at same place

````
SET @key_str = '3C5QYgFQr9AARjMyLNNQ3fL8QauXLTz0';
SET @iv = 'kaNUE3JAIVB9Em9v';
SET @ciphertext = AES_ENCRYPT('Hello', @key_str, @iv);
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(@ciphertext, @key_str, @iv);```
````

My requirement is to use aes-256-cbc encryption using MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MariaDB, you should read the MariaDB documentation, not the MySQL documentation.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/aes_encrypt/ shows `AES_ENCRYPT()` only has two arguments. This matches the implementation of that function as of MySQL 5.5, when MariaDB forked from MySQL in 2010. Since then, MySQL 5.7 and later changed the function to accept more arguments.

In general, you shouldn't think of MariaDB and MySQL as variants of the same product anymore. They have both changed significantly since they forked, and there are many cases where they are no longer compatible.

---

Here's a feature request for MariaDB to support the IV and block encryption mode: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9069

As of 2022-12-12 (version 10.10 is current as I write this), the feature is not yet implemented. So there is no support currently in MariaDB for CBC or other encryption modes. It still functions as it did in MySQL 5.5.

Comment: Already checked https://mariadb.com/kb/en/aes_encrypt/ but dosen't show how to use CBC with IV

Comment: And given what I wrote above, what does that tell you?

Comment: Got the point that they both are different, But still how to use aes-256-cbc encryption using mariaDB

Comment: See my edit above.